# Создание лицензии для плагина на Python+Django?

Tags: python, django

Представим, имеется простой сайт на Python+Django. В будущем планируется написать несколько плагинов, которые хотелось бы распространять по лицензии, следовательно нужно как то реализовать эту лицензию максимально надежным способом.

Загуглив, нашел вариант выноса проверки лицензии + части логики в C-ишный файл. В рамках сайта на Python+Django насколько это реальный и надежный вариант?

Какие еще есть надежные методы для реализации настоящей задачи?

Comment: Это вполне реальный и надёжный вариант.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону .pyc файлов: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files